# Magento category shown, but not loading properly?

Tags: magento, categories

I created three categories, cat1, cat2 and cat3. None of them has any products so far. Now, when I click cat2 on the frontend, it wont load properly, meaning, it loads forever without finishing. The other 2 categories load just fine and display the "no products in this category" message. I reindexed, cleared the cache, nothing helped. There are no errors in the log files.

When I clicked cat2, nothing else works in the store until I clear the var/session folder completely.

I am running Magento 1.9.1.1.

Any idea what might help?

Thanks!

Comment: are there any settings for this category? you can reset it. also maybe there  is a line in the code checking for that category id and then loading extra..

Comment: No settings for that category. It happens randomly as I noticed lately. It also happens fpr categories I just created.